release flutter app iOS for mac(ipad) for M1 and Intel
I have an app made in Flutter that I would like to build for macOS (the one designed for iPad is fine). However, I can only build it for arm64, which includes the M1, M2 family, etc., but I also want to build it for Intel. How can I do this?
This is my settings:



Now, if I search for my app on the App Store (from a Mac), I can only find it if I have an M1, M2, or M3, but not if I have an Intel.

You cannot run iOS apps on Intel-based Macs natively. This capability is exclusive to Apple Silicon Macs, as they share the same architecture with iOS devices. This shared architecture is what enables iOS apps to run on macOS seamlessly on Apple Silicon. You can read the full article here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/running-your-ios-apps-in-macos
Also please read this note on the same article:
"Although you can run your iOS apps unmodified on a Mac with Apple silicon, Mac Catalyst lets you build your app specifically for macOS and customize your app’s behavior on that platform. Mac Catalyst also supports deployment on both Apple silicon and Intel-based Mac computers. For more information about how to build your app with Mac Catalyst, see Mac Catalyst."

so if i have a m1 mac i cant distribute an app for a mac with intel processor?

What I mean is that if your app is an iOS app, Apple gives the option on Apple Silicon processors to run your iOS app on the Mac (as if it were native), but to run it on an Intel mac, your app must be built for Mac.
